# DataAnnotations validation in Web API, how to display in Swagger?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, documentation, swagger, swashbuckle

I'm developing an API using ASP.NET 4.6 and Web API 2. So far, I've been using DTO's and DataAnnotations, which look like the following:

```
public class CustomerDTO
{
    ...
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessageResourceName = "Error", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources), MinimumLength = 6)]
    public string DocumentNumber { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

And I'd use my DTO's like this:

```
[ResponseType(typeof(CustomerDTO))]
public IHttpActionResult PostCustomer(CustomerDTO customer)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    ...
}
```

Now I've been asked to release a first version of the API's documentation. After doing some research I discovered Swagger, so I got Swashbuckle from NuGet and started playing with it. Amazing, by the way.

But I do need the users of my API to know which is the max length for certain parameters, which ones are required, and so on. How do I get Swagger to show this information?

Answer (score 0):

see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35879582/3202422) the answer

[StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 5)]
public String Name {get;set;}