# Data annotations in Swagger

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

I am using ASP.NET and Swagger that exposes a complex type that accepts a POST. It has a number of string fields that have different restricted lengths. How can I reflect that in the Swagger UI?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can annotate the properties with the `StringLengthAttribute` from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations`.

For instance:

```
[StringLength(10)]
public String Name {get;set;}
```

will become:

```
"name": {
    "minLength": 0,
    "maxLength": 10,
    "type": "string"
}
```

And this:

```
[StringLength(10, MinimumLength = 5)]
public String Name {get;set;}
```

becomes:

```
"name": {
    "minLength": 5,
    "maxLength": 10,
    "type": "string"
}
```

Besides `StringLength` Swashbuckle also supports the `Range` and `RegularExpression` attributes.

**Update**

`MaxLength` does not work. `StringLength` does. However, discovering this information in Swagger UI is a bit clumsy. You have to navigate to the `Model` of your object and then hover over the property:

[image: How to discover max length info]

Comment: Thanks. I was using the MaxLength attribute. But neither display the "maxLength": 10 part in the Swagger UI.

Comment: I agree it is a bit clumsy. The hover bit doesn't even really work when you have more then one of these annotations. They will stack on top of each other and you don't know to which field they are referring. Thank for a great answer though.

Comment: The latest version stable version of `Swashbuckle` incorporates a new version of `Swagger UI` that fixes the stacked boxes.

Comment: Check out ReDoc, it a lot nicer than Swagger UI, only thing still missing for me is interactive api console.

Comment: MaxLength works for ASP.NET core and Swashbuckle at least now.   Still have to hover to see max length unfortunately.

Comment: I can confirm that MaxLength and MinLength work in current Core 2.2.

Comment: Thanks. This works well and shows maxlength when you hover over it but when I type string in input control it allows me to type characters more than the maximum length. I am using Swashbuckle 5.6.0 for ASP .Net application.

Comment: What this becomes? [Description("26\"")] TwentySix = 1