# Does Swashbuckle and Swagger allow specifying maximum string lengths?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, swagger, swashbuckle

Using XML comments and auto discovery with Swashbuckle and Swagger for Web API 2, is it possible to decorate properties in such a way that information about maximum string length is shown in the swagger ui? 
For example, the below uses 'manual' decoration with an XML comment - is there some other way of configuring the actual max length to appear in the swagger UI?

```
public class SomeClass
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Invoice number - maximum 15 characters
    /// </summary>
    public string InvoiceNumber {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: I think this is what you're looking http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35580517/data-annotations-in-swagger

Comment: @ArnaudLauret - perfect, thanks a lot!